# Adobe AIR cryptography native extension sample

Tags: security, actionscript-3, cryptography, air-native-extension

I am an Adobe AIR/AS3 developer and I need to use in my AIR application an encryption/decryption based on private/public keys.

I have found 2 cryptography native extensions:
https://github.com/vpmedia/botan-crypto-ane
https://github.com/vpmedia/cryptopp-ane

but neither of them has any documentation or samples in AS3. I would appreciate it if anyone would have any tips or samples of how i could encrypt a message with a public key and decrypt it with a private key, using either of the 2 aforementioned libraries.

I have generated my keys using an online "rsa key generator".

Comment: If you're looking for AS3 samples, you sure you need it in native extension? Can't you just do it in AS3 ?

Comment: I need the native extension because of performance issues, because pure AS3 implementations like http://crypto.hurlant.com/ are extremely slow, and will be using this in a client-server scheme, with the server handling possibly many operations.

Comment: Fair enough. How about adding to your project ANE from https://github.com/vpmedia/cryptopp-ane/tree/master/release and check APIs and code completion from your IDE?

Comment: I have, and as visible here: https://github.com/vpmedia/cryptopp-ane/blob/master/extension/src/main/actionscript/com/docmet/extensions/CryptoPPExtension.as , the AS3 implementation is pretty basic, based mostly on the createInstance() and callNative(...args) functions. Beyond this, the only documentation is the C++ documentation of Crypto++ itself, which unfortunately is a bit too advanced for me.

Comment: I think you'll need more expertise in crypto functions -- you can probably work out what arguments to pass to either lib if you know the underlying crypto library, but those ANEs are more like starting points than actual solutions.

Comment: Furthermore, both ANEs are written by the same programmer.  They're basically the same code except for which crypto lib they call.  Both ANEs lack ios support -- the `callNative` function just returns false!

Comment: @Htmiel as3-Crypto isn't not so slow, check other releases then original, for example https://github.com/mangui/as3-crypto has word based AES encryption which works much more (~25 time) faster then original one and helped me with the huge files even with the mobile development.

Comment: OK, I will give the github version a try and see how it works.

Comment: I have tested, and unfortunately, as expected with the pure AS3 library, an RSA decryption using a private key takes ~350ms for a very short message.

Comment: I also tested with a 2048bit RSA key and the encryption took 118ms, which is nice, but the decryption took 2500ms. And the decryption speed is what I am mostly interested in.

Comment: Looks like that AES-128 was optimized mostly.

Comment: *"I also tested with a 2048bit RSA key and the encryption took 118ms... but the decryption took 2500ms"* - You should probably look for another library. Both those numbers seem awfully high, which means the operations are awfully slow. I'd expect to see a 2048-bit encryption take about 0.03 ms, and a decryption about 1.24 ms on modern hardware.